# Infinite non cyclic group with proper subgroups being cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, infinite-groups

I was thinking about the question regarding infinite groups with all of its proper subgroups being cyclic but the group itself is not cyclic. The finite case is a well known fact $(K_4)$. I have found this beautiful counterexample for infinite groups [here](http://danaernst.com/an-infinite-non-cyclic-group-whose-proper-subgroups-are-cyclic/) about $$\left\langle \frac{a}{2^k} \mid a\in \mathbb{Z}, k \in \mathbb{N} \right\rangle.$$
Any prime $p$ would have done the job besides $2$. Now my question is the following-

Are there any other groups satisfying this property?

Comment: See here [Is there some sort of classification of all minimal non-cyclic groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210201/is-there-some-sort-of-classification-of-all-minimal-non-cyclic-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the answer of the same author.

Comment: Some authors have mentioned "Tarski monsters". But there are also torsion-free 2-generated groups with the same property (due to Olshanskii around 1980), and the construction of such groups is a *much* easier application of Gromov-hyperbolicity that the finite exponent version.

Comment: By the way the group you mention, usually known as $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$, does **not** satisfy the claimed property (unlike the claim in the linked post). Indeed $3\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$ is a proper, non-cyclic subgroup (of index 3).

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Look up Tarski monster group. Given a prime $p$, this is an infinite simple group all of whose proper subgroups are finite cyclic of order $p$. They exist for all large enough $p$.

Answer (score 2):

For instance the [Tarski monster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski_monster_group) group has the property that it is finitely generated, infinite and every proper subgroup is a cyclic group of a fixed prime order $p$.

Comment: I don't think there is a particular group that is called "the" Tarski monster. There is a construction, making use of plenty of choices, providing many groups. Choices can be made so as to produce a recursive presentation, but this is not canonical at all.

Comment: @YCor: True, is is a class of groups, I should have called it a "group of the Tarski monster class." But OP does not seem to care one way or another...

Comment: No, just "a Tarski monster group" is fine, rather than "the Tarski monster group".